# Convert Javascript text variable to plain text in an existing text file

Tags: javascript, html

I am saving user input from a html input as a javascript variable. I want to convert this data into plain text in an existing text file. Essentially, every time the user inputs, their input is converted to plain text and placed into a text file. New inputs only add to the text in the text file.

I tried using node.js and appending to the text file, but it didn't seem to respond and work.

Comment: You need a backend server to accomplish this. You can't modify a text file from a browser. Also, you can't send JavaScript variables to your server so it's going to be serialized one way or another

Comment: Your second paragraph makes no sense. Node.js is an entire programming language, it can append things to text files perfectly fine. Read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post to include all the details you left out.

Comment: do write your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....
Create one test.txt initially...
Creating the endpoint in node
Using the same using fetch call in javascript code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="floatingInputGroup1"
          placeholder="Username"
        />
        <label for="floatingInputGroup1">Username</label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-primary" onclick="handleSubmit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var userInput = document.getElementById("floatingInputGroup1");
    async function handleSubmit() {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/", {
        // Adding method type
        method: "POST",

        // Adding body or contents to send
        body: JSON.stringify({
          enteredValue: userInput.value
        }),

        // Adding headers to the request
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      })
        //MESSAGE
        .then(() => 
        console.log("SUCCESS"))
    }
  </script>
</html>
```